# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, access-denied

I am trying to fetch records from database. but I am facing this access denied issue. I tried the other solutions mentioned on Stack Overflow like granting privilege to the user.. but none worked.

Code for accessing database :

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.println("<html>");
  out.println("<head><title>Servlet JDBC</title></head>");
  out.println("<body>");
  out.println("<h1>Servlet JDBC</h1>");
  out.println("</body></html>");  
  // connecting to database
  Connection con = null;  
  Statement stmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees","root","root");
      stmt = con.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee");
      // displaying records
      while(rs.next()){
      out.print(rs.getObject(1).toString());
      out.print("\t\t\t");
      out.print(rs.getObject(2).toString());
      out.print("<br>");
  }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new ServletException("Servlet Could not display records.", e);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      throw new ServletException("JDBC Driver not found.", e);
  } finally {
      try {
          if(rs != null) {
              rs.close();
              rs = null;
          }
          if(stmt != null) {
              stmt.close();
              stmt = null;
          }
          if(con != null) {
              con.close();
              con = null;
          }
      } catch (SQLException e) {}
  }
    out.close();
  }
```

Stack trace of the error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:927)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4686)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1304)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    WebAppAss.DatabaseAccess.service(DatabaseAccess.java:36)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

What could be the problem in this case. I tried creating a new database but that didn't work too.

Comment: Password could be wrong.

Comment: no it isnt.. I login in the mysql using the same password

Comment: Can you show us the command you used to grant access?

Comment: are you sure that it's using port 3306 ? (yes i know that it's the default port number, but it is port 80 at me because i'm using it with Apache)

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON employees.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root'

Comment: Go through all [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/access-denied.html) first !

Comment: I used this command as mentioned in the link but even this didnt work :
mysqladmin -uroot -proot flush-hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the permissions granted to root in the `information.schema` table. 'root'@'%' didnt have any permissions.. And as I was using `127.0.0.1` as my connection address, so it was giving the access denied error.. `%` is the wildcard for an ip address. so mysql considers `root@127.0.0.1` as any other ip address but not `localhost`. so just granting it permission solved my problem.. Try using some Mysql client like `SQLYog` etc.. it is easy to grant the privileges and also to view the privileges with the user.

Comment: I had the same error and even after adding a user 'root'@'%', granting it all permissions the same error is coming. Access Denied for 'root'@'localhost'(using password(yes))

Comment: did you try to add root@localhost to information.schema?

Answer (score 4):

Start mysql client in the console and execute this query: `select Host, User from mysql.user;`. You MUST have a row like this:

```
+----------------+------------------+  
| Host           | User             |  
+----------------+------------------+  
| localhost      | root             |
+----------------+------------------+
```

a row with "localhost" in **Host** and "root" in **User**. If you don't have it that's the cause of your problem (it doesn't matter if you have other rows with "root" in **User**)

If you don't have such row, add a new user with this:

```
CREATE USER 'appUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'appPassword';
```

Change 'appUser' by 'root' if you want, but I strongly suggest to use another user. Then add permissions to your new user by executing this in the mysql client:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON employees.* TO 'appUser'@'localhost';
```

(again, change 'appUser' by 'root' if you want)

Comment: I already have the root user in users... I created a new user but the command u mentioned to grant privileges gave the following error :

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'previliges on employees.*
to 'dbUser'@'localhost'' at line 1

Comment: you have a typo: "previliges" instead of "privileges"

Comment: the command ran successfully.. but still same error.. the new user I created was with the name 'dbUser' but still when I run my application, it is giving the same error that access denied for 'root' even when I changed the name to dbUser in the connection string

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
mysql --no-defaults --force --user=root --host=localhost --database=mysql
```

Change a new password:

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD') where USER='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks Gustavo. That above query help me in flushing the privileges for the root.