# JDBC Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans, connectivity

This is an error for me.
I have used proper password as this is what I type when I start MySQL.

```
DefaultTableModel dtm=(DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
dtm.setRowCount(0);
try{
    Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
    Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/shashvat","root","1234");
    Statement s=c.createStatement();       
    ResultSet r=s.executeQuery("select * from phasetests;");

    while(r.next()){
        Object arr[]={r.getString(1),r.getString(2),r.getString(3),r.getString(4)};
        dtm.addRow(arr);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e.getMessage());   
}
```

The Exception Message:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have tried this too:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17908407/5036731

The problem still persists.
Please help.

Comment: There is no Port Number is specified in that Connection string

Comment: @Assen Specifying a port number is not necessary, it will then use the default port number.

Comment: you need to change this `Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");` its not finding the driver in first place

Comment: I have used same code elsewhere and it works. If driver is not found it gives driver not found exception. I tried changing it anyways but still doesn't work.

Comment: @ShashvatJayakrishnan, is your MySQL service is running?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Your code should be something like this.

```
DefaultTableModel dtm=(DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
dtm.setRowCount(0);
try{ 
    //Class.forName("java.sql.Driver"); This is wrong
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // Declare it like this..
    Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shashvat","root","1234"); // port number was missing
    Statement s=c.createStatement();       
    ResultSet r=s.executeQuery("select * from phasetests;");

    while(r.next()){
        Object arr[]={r.getString(1),r.getString(2),r.getString(3),r.getString(4)};
        dtm.addRow(arr);
    } 
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e.getMessage());   
}
```

See the code I mentioned here is working. I checked it locally. The problem should be with the **password** or **schema access** for which you can refer following.

[Access Denied for User 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - No Privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges)

If it's a problem with privileges. Grant all privileges to root by executing following command.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON shashvat.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root'
```

[ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y)

Comment: Port number is not required, and using `Class.forName` hasn't been necessary since JDBC 4.0 (Java 6).

Comment: I have made required changes but it is still giving the same exception. Moreover the code which I have posted works on other computers but not on mine.

Comment: @ShashvatJayakrishnan- Are you able to connect mysql using workbench or some other database IDE tool using user name **'root'** and password **'1234'**?

Comment: I had seen other questions on this site and already did grant privileges but still doesn't work. I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: I will try it again.

Comment: @ChiragParmar what is schema access?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below mentioned syntax

```
   Connection c =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql"+"://"+host+":"+port+"/"+db,"root","pass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just correct your Driver name to com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
and add host with port  localhost:3306